# Looking for a sci-fi book name with a giant space monster swallowing a ship

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, evolution

I am looking for the name of a sci fi book I have read when I was a kid. Obviously I do not remember the name of the book nor the author's...

Here is a short summary of the story, spoiler ahead!

The story takes place on a spaceship that has been swallowed by a giant space monster. There are two survivors among the crew, they decide to make the monster evolve so it will land on a planet and allow them to escape. They eventually succeed, the monster evolves, lands on a planet and dies, giving birth to a race of sentient lizards. In the last chapter, the last remaining survivor goes into a cryogenic sleep and is awaken centuries later by humans.

Does anybody know the title? I know the description is a bit vague... I read this in the mid 90s so it is not very recent.

Many thanks for your help!